# ImageMagick command line convert -limit values

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I need to convert an extremely large image. The default resource limits of Image Magick are far too small.

The Image Magick website [discusses changing the limits](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php), but none of the syntaxes I've tried have worked, the commands aren't recognized.

For instance, I need to set the magick_disk_limit to something like 25GB. Then there will be a series of others to set, magick_area_limit, magick_height_limit, etc. How do I enter those commands?

What I've tried is

```
-limit width 100KP
convert -limit width 100KP
magick_disk_limit 25GB
MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT 25GB
```

In all cases the response is either command not found, or unrecognized resource type. I also tried putting in a convert command with all the -limit parameters defined as part of the command, like this:

```
convert -limit 100KP 100KP 100GP 14GiB 100GiB unlimited 5 8 0 unlimited Lunar_LRO_LrocKaguya_DEMmerge_60N60S_512ppd.tif MoonRelief.png
```

I have now tried `export MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=25GiB`, but then when I enter `identify -list resource` the Disk limit hasn't changed.

```
convert -limit memory 12GB -limit map 25GiB -limit width 10MP -limit height 10MP -limit area 100GP -limit disk 30GiB Lunar_LRO_LrocKaguya_DEMmerge_60N60S_512ppd.tif MoonRelief.png
```

generates this list of warnings and errors

```
convert-im6.q16: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/912.
convert-im6.q16: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/912.
convert-im6.q16: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/912.
convert-im6.q16: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/912.
convert-im6.q16: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/912.
convert-im6.q16: Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/912.
convert-im6.q16: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/912.
convert-im6.q16: width or height exceeds limit `Lunar_LRO_LrocKaguya_DEMmerge_60N60S_512ppd.tif' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3837.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `MoonRelief.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? How are the commands not recogized? Please [edit] your question and clarify, *do not* use comments. Did you try setting the variables with e.g. `export MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=25GB` and running ImageMagick in *the same* terminal?

Comment: @dessert okay, I specified that now.

Comment: Please try it with an SI prefix, e.g. `export MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=25GB` (not `GiB`!) – that’s what the site you linked says… If you want 25GiB, use `…=27GB` instead.

Comment: @dessert I did it that way because when I list the current resource limits, the disk limit is shown as 1GiB. So I just stuck with the units as shown on my system. Memory and Map are shown in MiB. I have tried asking on the ImageMagick forum now and am about to go through a solution they suggested.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was able to [find a solution through the ImageMagick forum](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=34044&p=156413#p156413).

The method was to change the settings for Resource limits in the file handling that in ImageMagick, called policy.xml. In Ubuntu 18.04 that is found in `/etc/ImageMagick-6`. It is set as read-only, so I temporarily changed the write permissions with `sudo chmod 777 policy.xml` from within that folder. After making the changes, I switched the permission to 744.

This is what the relevant section of policy.xml looks like:

```xml
<policymap>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/tmp"/> -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="14GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="30GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16MP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16MP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="40GP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="30GiB"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="0"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="3600"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- not needed due to the need to use explicitly by mvg: -->
  <!-- <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
  <!-- use curl -->
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />
  <!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>
  <policy domain="cache" name="shared-secret" value="passphrase" stealth="true"/>
</policymap>
```

The parts that needed changing already have the values I substituted in so I can process the image in question. They are the 3rd to the 8th line, the resource named "memory" to the resource named "disk".

After making those changes, checking in the terminal with `identify -list resource` returns the new values.

Comment: You can also set the `MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH` environment variable to point to any directory that contains your `policy.xml` file.

Comment: This works !!!
For the clarification, I will mention the lines that need to change in policy.xml

Comment: Thanks for this. Hopefully the authors of image-magick see the popularity of this question and realize their default limits of width and height are far too low.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say what you tried, and I suspect a case problem "`magick_area_limit`" is not the same as "`MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT`".

but here are two ways:

Start `imagemagick` from a script :

```
#!/bin/bash
export MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=42GiB
export MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT=42MP
# etc ...
imagemagic "$@"
```

or, use the `env` command:

```
env MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=42GiB MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT=42MP imagemagick ...
```

Comment: *Define arguments for the MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT, MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT, and MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT environment variables with SI prefixes (.e.g 100MB).*

Comment: See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#disk-limit and read the whole page, and the links. This is no longer about Ubuntu, it's about ImageMagick, and they have a web page.

Comment: @dessert See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#disk-limit This is no longer about Ubuntu, it's about ImageMagick.

Comment: I have been to the page you mention, but it doesn't explain how to change them, and the way it works in Ubuntu seems to be a bit different too. I don't know about Image Magick not being part of Ubuntu, it was just there without me installing it.  The main commands function without first putting 'magick', the way it's done on other OS for which they have an installation package. (I'm trying your solution now.)

Comment: Did you read the whole page? At the end, it says "Define arguments for the MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT, MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT, and MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT environment variables with SI prefixes (.e.g 100MB). MAGICK_WIDTH_LIMIT, MAGICK_HEIGHT_LIMIT and MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT accepts pixel suffixes such as MP for mega-pixels (e.g. 100MP)."

Comment: I did read the whole section, and I used the proper units. Using `env MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT=25GiB imagemagick` returned `env: 'imagemagick' : No such file or directory`. I don't know how to use a script.

Comment: This is great, but one caveat. https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php says "you can restrict limits relative to any security policies, but you cannot relax them." So *decreasing* the values with environment variables works, but increasing them doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I am using ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS this is an extension to answer from @kim holder

Go to `sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

Change the below lines to enable convert image with large size.

```
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="14GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="30GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16MP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16MP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="40GP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="30GiB"/>
```

Read the original answer as well 
https://askubuntu.com/a/1041633/970339

Thanks, Hope this clarifies to do the fix fast.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I only changed the `width` and `height` value of `policy.xml`

```
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16MP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16MP"/>
```

Also before changing anything in configuration file it's good practice to take a backup so just copy the file in the same directory with a `.bak` filename.

```
sudo cp -v policy.xml policy.xml.bak
```

You can copy the file other places but that may change the ownership and permission.

Answer (score 0):

I manage this issue on a VPS and don't have so many resources, so just change a little these 3 values :

```bash
<policy domain="resource" name="width" value="24KP"/> <!-- default 16KP -->
<policy domain="resource" name="height" value="24KP"/> <!-- default 16KP -->
…
<policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="3GiB"/> <!-- default 1GiB -->
```

and picture 7803x19208 could be resized !